# Unable to generate JFR report from Weblogic Server 10.3.6

Tags: java, weblogic, jvm-hotspot, jrockit

I'm running Weblogic Server 10.3.6 and trying to get a JFR report using Java Mission Control. The server exists in my Linux VM and I'm trying to connect to the process from my windows machine using the Mission Control client. While trying to connect, I'm encountering the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JRockit is no longer supported. Use a 4.x version of Mission Control when connecting to a JRockit.
```

I thought it might help my providing the following startup args before starting my Weblogic server:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures 
-XX:+FlightRecorder
```

But that did not help as the startup failed mentioning:

```
Unknown option or illegal argument: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures. 
Please check for incorrect spelling or review documentation of startup options.
```

Connecting to the server from the Mission control client has worked for me before but i guess it was an older version of WLS. Could someone help me figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are running WLS with the JRockit JVM?
In that case you need to run JRockit Mission Control (jrmc) instead of Java Mission Control (jmc)
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures and -XX:+FlightRecorder are not needed and do not exist for JRockit.